# What's the best way to optimise the fixture-loading part of Django tests?

Tags: python, django, testing, performance, fixtures

my Django tests run really slowly, but it's not the test's fault.

At the moment, the whole process takes 14s, but only 0.1s of that is running tests. The first few seconds are creating tables & indexes, the rest is applying the project's many `fixtures`.

What's the best way to deal with this? I think there is a way of specifying which `fixtures` to load in each test, but I need most of them to do most tests...

A solution I think would work is if the tests didn't drop the tables after each run, that way there would be no need to create & populate the database each run-through of the tests. Most tests don't even write to the DB.

What's the best way to optimise the `fixture`-loading part of Django tests?
Thanks!

(I'm using `nose`, but otherwise just plain Django and `sqlite`)

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I'm using an in-memory sqlite database. What I'm looking for - specifically - is an optimisation of the fixture-loading section of the test.

Comment: You could try to wrap the fixture-loading in a transaction to speed it up. If you're using MySQL with InnoDB tables, that should make a big difference.

Comment: I'm already using an in-memory sqlite database, I don't think that can be optimised much furthur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "but I need most of them to do most tests"...

Sorry about this, but to speed things up you're going to have to do some **thinking**.

> "I think there is a way of specifying which fixtures to load in each test"

This is a disturbing thing to read.  Have you **looked** at your tests recently?

Your tests do -- specifically -- list the fixtures.  You need to minimize that list.

Comment: I don't follow your answer, wow do I minimize the list of fixtures?

Comment: @Oatman: 1.  You look at the list.  2.  You think about the test.  3.  You remove fixtures not needed for the test.  4.  You remove data items from the fixtures not needed for the test.  You **think** about what each test does.  You **minimize** the list of fixtures for each test.

Comment: How do I remove fixtures not needed for the test? initial_data.json files are loaded before my tests run...

Comment: Oatman: 4. You remove data items from the fixtures not needed for the test.   You can edit the JSON file, you know.  You can have different JSON files for each test.

Comment: OK, with you so far. How do I use individual fixtures with each test, what code do I put in the test?

Comment: @Oatman: I do not understand your question.  Please read this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/testing/#fixture-loading

Comment: AHA! I think I understand now. I should stop using initial_data.json, moving the data into other json files, which I then specify in my tests. Got it.

Comment: Although the tone of your answer and comments were very inflammatory and arrogant, you did lead me to the right answer, thanks!

Comment: @Oatman: "very inflammatory and arrogant" Odd that you would perceive them that way.  Your questions are very, very hard to answer.  It seems like you're withholding information.  It's very unclear to me what you know, what you don't know, and what code you have  in place.  Lacking any factual details, it's very, very hard to be more helpful.  In the future, consider adding details like code samples to your questions.

Comment: Very arrogant,  It doesn't hurt to be nicer, people appreciate your help more.

Comment: I gotta say that I knew even before seeing who wrote this answer that it was @S.Lott.  Clearly extremely smart and knowledgeable, but also forgets that many of us don't have the 30+ years experience he does.

Answer (score 4):

You may use sqlite in-memory database for tests - it really fast

Comment: Thanks, but not with a few megs of fixtures! I'm already using in-memory database :-(